# PyQt5 - How to recognize which button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was looking and saw some places that people use a sender() and then convert it to text, sender.text()

like this:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    printf(sender.text())
    self.openFileNameDialog(0)
```

But my code exits the going to the sender.text()

I want to pass the specific button to the function `self.openFileNameDialog(0)`

Comment: the button is `self.sender()`. Use `self.openFileNameDialog(self.sender())`

Comment: But what do self.sender() return? if I should make an if, that can do something different depending on which button is pressed

Comment: `self.sender()` returns the object that emits the signal, and in its case is the button that was pressed since the signal that is emits is the clicked.

Comment: @Jamesdawn Use the `is` operator to test for a specific button: `if sender is self.button01: ... elif sender is self.button02: ...` etc.

Comment: okay great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I made it work with help from ekhumoro.

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    self.openFileNameDialog(self.sender())

def openFileNameDialog(self, which_button):
    if which_button is pushButton:
        #do something
    if which_button is pushButton2:
        #do something
```